# How to add/remove edge loops in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

There is no loop cut node in Geometry Nodes. Is there a workaround to add loop cuts/edge loops in GN?

Comment: One possibility https://youtu.be/q2JqOVp-mEo

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do it with limitations. Add Merge by distance node to the end if you want to merge vertices.

[image: Cutter example]
[image: Using Grid Plane as cutter]

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** This answer may no longer be up-to-date for Blender 4.0+. Even if there is still no satisfactory/simple solution for this problem, there may be (computationally expensive or useful for some use cases) alternatives.

This time, unfortunately, the answer is: **No, it does not work.**

With *Geometry Nodes* you can only subdivide an existing mesh with the nodes `Subdivide Mesh` and `Subdivision Surface`. However, neither of these nodes provide any way to specifically subdivide or split in certain areas.

The only other possibility would be to build two (or more) completely new meshes, but this would not be procedurally feasible at the moment due to the multitude of possibilities.

Therefore, this question has to be answered unsatisfactorily, and I'm afraid this won't change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

here is another approach and it does work on 4.0.2[image]

Comment: Could you please explain a little about what exactly you are doing here? Because without an explanation and without a blend file, I'm afraid this answer is not very helpful for others. Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: right, so this GN setup does loopcuts on 3 axis, you can add multiple nodes destributed on even distance with control over starting point, or you can add single loopcut and control starting point and axis. This GN also quite heavy if you wanna chop cube in hundreds loopcuts, however at the end this does the job.