# Model Reinforcing Bar with Geometry Nodes

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]

How can I make e reinforcing bar from a line in Geometry Nodes?

Comment: why don't you just use a normal map. it would work just as well (unless you need very close up shot) and your computer will thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previously I got a little bit too inspired by Harry's answer, so here's something that better resembles a reinforcement bar - but the topology here is just overlapping geometries, so you won't get any nice merging of the separate surfaces…

[image]

[image]

Again, I got bored without actually finishing, so there's (conveniently not shown) one rib too much (trivial to fix), no rectangular emboss joining the 'bulges' and small things like that. It seems a 'correct' topology could still be constructed using my previous answer but different $z$ offsetting…

[image]

Comment: whoops checked the zoomed rebar image from Robin, didnt realize the real pattern of the rebar 

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie in a way, I think the spiral is harder, because it's continuous, while this pattern here can be separated…

Comment: yes agreed. it was also more fun to model hehe, nice smooth minimalist topology u made though!

Comment: Thanks for the great help, it's really great. Your method helped me a lot. I am new to geo nodes. Is it possible to add a vertical line and remove one top section? https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKAh.jpg

Comment: @AndreyRe in this case the vertical line is just aligning a cuboid ("Cube" node), and the top section is disabling the "Fill Caps" in the maroon (red) "Bar" frame.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKAh.jpg

Comment: @AndreyRe Yes, I was just lazy not removing this one instance, consider replacing the "Curve to Points" with https://i.imgur.com/dqDnudR.png

Comment: @AndreyRe and this is how you could fit the cuboid, also notice I moved "set smooth" elsewhere (to the cap frame) https://i.imgur.com/x7fvtz6.png

Comment: Thank you))) it worked)))

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit tricky and hard if not impossible when using the Cylinder node, especially adding of Loop Cuts or subdivisions on specific areas ([which is not really supported in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255306/how-to-add-remove-edge-loops-in-geometry-nodes)). But you can create a cylinder by plotting the vertices using the [Spherical Coordinate System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) so that you can easily shift the vertices on the XY plane to give it twisted geometry. While you can easily do this via menu *Add > Mesh > Math Function > XYZ Math Surface*, it is also possible with Geometry Nodes using the simple [Parametric Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) similar to that of plotting a circle:
$$x(u) = r \times \cos(u)$$
$$y(u) = r \times \sin(u)$$
$$z(v) = h \times v$$

[image]

Here is the node setup to create the twisted cylinder, which I put in a [`Node Group`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/groups.html) called *Twist Cylinder*:

[image]

And this is the node setup that uses the node group I created above. This setup extrudes and creates the ribs for the rebar:

[image]

Please take note that this node setup is not perfect, it requires some bug fixes, but what's important is you get the idea on how to do this.

[image]

Comment: This is heroic.. could you not just (curve-to-mesh) send a profile down a curve-line tilted by some multiple of its own  curve parameter, to twist it? Maybe the topology would be a bit tortured.

Comment: @RobinBetts maybe won't be as flexible to customize? i'm not sure, i'm also still a geonodes noob and practicing haha i'd be interested to see the solution! :)

Comment: .. I've been stuck on mine.. trying to find a neat way, given the solid is not actually a spiral. The 2 halves are reflections of one another, offset down the length.

Comment: @RobinBetts at first I did exactly what Markus did with the offsetting of the Z, but I didn't know how to flatten the top and bottom and now realize i just had to clamp it like he explained, could've ended up with his better topology XD

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would approach a minimal topology, though this setup still isn't finished, you might want to add the control for rib thickness for example, or you might want to add a falloff of the ribs towards the ends (I simulated a bar that is cut rather than produced with this length…) - but it shows the principle of taking a cylinder, cutting it and shearing - though after an initial try with a cylinder I figured it would be easier to just start with a grid:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh and the dimensions are wrong, basically the default $xy$ dimensions mean a radius of $1$ without taking the extrusion into account, so… Yeah… The $z$ dimension should be fine.

Comment: nice gave it +1 but just took a look now, i wanted to skew the vertical edges upwards while keeping the top/bottom flat, instead of skewing the horizontal edges, but the noob me couldn't manage how to do it, so i ended up skewing horizontally XD

Comment: Very nice cope with the topo!  :) .. although I'm still trying to reverse-engineer your strategy from your node-tree. (And.. the ref. rebar isn't actually a spiral? .. That's kind of a BTW)

Comment: @RobinBetts why isn't it a spiral? I offset each circle by the angle, so it's a linear offset along each circle. Here's a comparison with the "Spiral" node, unless you meant it in a way that the "Spiral" node not always produces a spiral (because a spiral should change radius?). As for the strategy: take the cylinder, shear it: https://i.imgur.com/nRJdh3s.gif , clamp the $z$ coordinates to flatten top and bottom, and extrude every 2nd (original) horizontal face-loop. I don't start with a cylinder, because splitting and differentiating sides of the split is harder than sin+cos.

Comment: whoops, here's the comparison with the spiral https://i.imgur.com/pgBvin6.png

Comment: Hi, Markus Thanks for the explanation! I read the rebar as opposite spirals/diagonals, reflected across a flat/raised section, offset in length: https://imgur.com/a/0MmPnPc .. but curiously, different on different bars.. perhaps manufacturing rollers can go in and out of phase.

Comment: @RobinBetts I think I got a little bit too inspired by Harry's answer... :) Reinforcement bars have various patterns, but a spiral one might be a bad one, because theoretically it would allow for some freedom of movement of such a rebar (if there was no friction and the rebar was perfectly stiff, it could be pushed - or pulled by gravity - away from the concrete). Usually I think the pattern is not spirals, just skewed circles / almost circles. I'll write another answer for that but without 'good' topo this time.