# screw thread with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create by geometry nodes something that could fit a threadend.
So common houshold plastic cans can be connected (screwed upon, akin to a bolt)

SO i created something but well it looks like it, but my usage will be for my 3D printer and its not good enough to do real things with this.
As i like to be able to measure something fill in my measurements and get the right shape. Below is a draft that ook me a long while to get (i'm not so good at geometry nodes).

But i want to be able to

- easily set the outer ring.
- easily set the thread hight (the height of the line tat needs to be taken out)
- easily set the thread depth (how deep it must be carved)
- how many times it should turn
- how many thread lines there are
- Be able to use metrics and not some weird 0..1 values
- 2 thread carving shapes, Thread square and thread traingje (or 45" roated square)

Well i think i came close but its in the fine tuning of my wishes that i dont know how to do it

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know you said Geometry Nodes, but have you looked at Blender's built-in BoltFactory addon? (Search 'bolt' under Preferences > addons.)

Comment: See the two not accepted answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/300293/60486 - the remesh option should be fine for 3d printing.