# When adding shape to spiral in geometry nodes it is revolving around axis - how to control it?

Tags: geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

I am trying to make something like a lead screw with blender, by joining cylinder and circle (with 4 points, so cube) along a spiral around it. But issue is that this rotating around spiral - how could I control that rotation?

Picture below might show more of what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set z-up normal:

[image]

Also maybe you're interested in this:

[Model Reinforcing Bar with Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/300433/60486)